# RemoteView in android notification on device theme switching

Tags: android, android-notifications, remoteview

I have a problem with a RemoteView in notifications. If the user switches the theme from day to night or back, the notification text theme remains the same. In the example below text remain black despite the theme, but I want to change correspondingly.

I've tried:

1. `DecoratedCustomViewStyle` + `setCustomContentView`
2. Compat `android:textAppearance`

Any advices? :)

I'm showing notification like this:

```
final NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
final String channelId = "channel_id";
        
manager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannelCompat.Builder(channelId,
                                                                        NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                                                  .setName("Test channel")
                                                  .build());
        
final RemoteViews customView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_notification_test);
        
final Notification n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId).setContent(customView)
                                                                      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notify_featured)
                                                                      .build();
        
manager.notify(1050, n);
```

view_notification_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/accent"
    android:layout_height="128dp">
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="custom view text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by using `values-night` folder for text colors and overriding `android:textColor` for the `TextView`.